# How does this ARM assembly instruction make sense?

Tags: assembly, arm, digital

I am building a processor that takes in 32-bit arm instructions and interprets/ executes them. It mostly works, except for a specific script with a weird BL instruction that doesn't seem like it should work.

For clarity, these bl instructions work just fine when executed normally (on a normal machine), but they don't work on my custom-built processor. I'm confused as to why they would ever work, as they don't seem to make sense. I got this data from objdump:

```
  e8:   ebfffffe        bl      b8 <merge_sort_s>
  ec:   e59d0004        ldr     r0, [sp, #4]
  f0:   e59d1008        ldr     r1, [sp, #8]
  f4:   e59d200c        ldr     r2, [sp, #12]
  f8:   e59d3010        ldr     r3, [sp, #16]
  fc:   e59d4014        ldr     r4, [sp, #20]
 100:   e1a01004        mov     r1, r4
 104:   e2811001        add     r1, r1, #1
 108:   ebfffffe        bl      b8 <merge_sort_s>
 10c:   e59d0004        ldr     r0, [sp, #4]
 110:   e59d1008        ldr     r1, [sp, #8]
 114:   e59d200c        ldr     r2, [sp, #12]
 118:   e59d3010        ldr     r3, [sp, #16]
 11c:   e59d4014        ldr     r4, [sp, #20]
 120:   ebfffffe        bl      0 <merge_s>
```

All of the BL instructions in this snippet have the exact same offset, 0xFFFFFE. This should not be the case, as they all have different distances required to branch to the desired instruction.

Is there something wrong with these instructions? Are they correct, and I just need to interpret them differently? Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: The way a compiler optimizes the code is sometimes surprising. Maybe show the whole C(?) code, and the whole ARM code?

Comment: You're probably disassembling a `.o`, so those are just placeholders to be filled in by the linker with the actual offsets to those symbols filled, when you link into an executable.  That would also explain the very low address in the disassembly.  A PIE executable normally doesn't start at zero, if that's a Linux executable.  But if that's `objdump` output, normally the actual relocation info would be in a comment, with the bogus target listed as `<foo+110>` or something.  So what commands did you use to build something and disassemble to get this output?

Comment: I actually wrote the code by hand in assembly, so I don't have C code to show.

Comment: I used "objdump -d mergesort_s.o"

Comment: @KeithMcConnel This is an object file.  It cannot be executed as is.  You have to link it first.  Then, the linker will fill in the correct offsets for these function calls.

Comment: @fuz. That seems to explain it! I'll do some more research on linkers, thank you.